# Upload single image file to FTP using PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, ftp

Pulling my hair out a bit here. All I want to do is have a HTML form and then PHP to upload the selected file to a certain directory on an FTP server, but nothing seems to be working correctly.

Here's the html form :

```
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input name="file" type="file" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

And here's the PHP below it (on the same file):

```
<?php
$ftp_server = "myftp.co.uk";
$ftp_user_name = "myusername";
$ftp_user_pass = "mypass";
$destination_file = "/public_html/my/directory/";
$source_file = $_POST['file']['tmp_name'];

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true); 

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass); 

// check connection
if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) { 
    echo "FTP connection has failed!";
    echo "Attempted to connect to $ftp_server for user $ftp_user_name"; 
    exit; 
} else {
    echo "Connected to $ftp_server, for user $ftp_user_name";
}

// upload the file
$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file, FTP_BINARY); 

// check upload status
if (!$upload) { 
echo "FTP upload has failed!";
} else {
echo "Uploaded $source_file to $ftp_server as $destination_file";
}

// close the FTP stream 
ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

It seems to connect to the FTP ok, but doesn't upload - failed. I'm assuming it's something to do with the way I'm handling the file to be uploaded..?

Also, while I'm here, how do I set the name of the file that's been uploaded as a variable?

Comment: Your $destination_file is a directory not the name of a file. It should be a file name

Comment: Ah! Now I see! How would I go about changing that so it is a directory?

Comment: You can make a directory by using the ftp_mkdir function http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-mkdir.php

Comment: do you know how to show uploaded image in html page?

Comment: The image file will now be stored on your server, if it's in a public directory you can just use img src=""...

Comment: Hi @ElliotReed. Did you eventually end up changing the $destination_file?

Comment: @Parsa_237 it was over 6 years ago now, but from the looks of it I was trying to use `$_POST` instead of `$_FILES` to upload the contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code here

```
$source_file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
```

Here i have changed $_POST to $_FILES....

Answer (score 0):

It seems fine with above code, but FTP passive command i.e ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);
should be after ftp_login or else it won't work.
You may get this kind of errors:
**ftp_put(): I won't open a connection to 172.xx.xx.xx (only to xx.xxx.xxx.xxx)**

```
<?php
$ftp_server = "your server or host";
$ftp_user_name = "username";
$ftp_user_pass = "password";
$ftp_port = "port";
$destination_file = "/public_html/my/directory/";
$source_file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server,$ftp_port);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass); 
// ftp passive cmd
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

// check connection
if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) { 
    echo "FTP connection has failed!";
    echo "Attempted to connect to $ftp_server for user $ftp_user_name"; 
    exit; 
} else {
    echo "Connected to $ftp_server, for user $ftp_user_name";
}

// upload the file
$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file, FTP_BINARY); 

// check upload status
if (!$upload) { 
echo "FTP upload has failed!";
} else {
echo "Uploaded $source_file to $ftp_server as $destination_file";
}

// close the FTP stream 
ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```