# How to upload files from one server to another using FTP - PHP?

Tags: php, ftp

I m trying to upload a file from the Plesk server to the HostGator server using the FTP details I created in HostGator.

The code is from [this query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18718321/upload-single-image-file-to-ftp-using-php). Which I presume works fine. But for some reason, the file is not bing uploaded.

**The code goes as:**

```
<?php
    $ftp_server = "the.servername";
    $ftp_user_name = "the@username";
    $ftp_user_pass = "thepassword";
    $destination_file = " ";
    $source_file = $_FILES['files']['name']; 

    // set up basic connection
    $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
    ftp_pasv($conn_id, true); 

    // login with username and password
    $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass); 

    // check connection
    if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) { 
        echo "FTP connection has failed!";
        echo "Attempted to connect to $ftp_server for user $ftp_user_name"; 
        exit; 
    } else {
        echo "Connected to $ftp_server, for user $ftp_user_name";
    }

    // upload the file
    $upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file, FTP_BINARY); 

    // check upload status
    if (!$upload) { 
    echo "FTP upload has failed!";
    } else {
    echo "Uploaded $source_file to $ftp_server as $destination_file";
    }

    // close the FTP stream 
    ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

Please note that the `destination_file` is empty as while I created the FTP logins in the HostGator, I clearly mentioned the folder the files have to upload. So I left this `destination_file` empty.

Now when I try to upload the error echo's as

`Connected to ftp.vdofyfilex.com, for user files_from_vdofy@vdofyfilex.comFTP upload has failed!`

As you can see, the connection was successful but the file was not uploading. could be because of `destination_file` is empty.

Things I have tried with `$destination_file`:

1. `$destination_file = 'added the full domain with directory'`
2. Added a sub folder as temp and `$destination_file = 'temp/'`
3. Added a sub folder as temp and `$destination_file = 'full domain with directory + temp/'`
4. `$destination_file = ''`

None of 'em worked.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, the `$remote_filename` parameter of `ftp_put` (`$destination_file` in you code). definitely cannot be empty. You need to fix that. Why didn't you try fixing that before asking, if you know that it is a potential problem?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Ok, understood, but I did even tried add a temp folder to the directory and kept the `$destination_file` as `temp/` as well. it still gave me the same error.

Comment: `temp/` is definitely not a valid file path. It should be like `/temp/filename` (or maybe `temp/filename`, if `temp` is a subfolder of your home folder). And *"full domain"* is also not file path. If you still do not make it working, post a screenshot of your favourite FTP client logged into your FTP server, so that we can see what are the paths like on your server.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I did these : `$destination_file = "/temp/tempfilename";` and `$destination_file = "/temp/".$source_file;`  none worked...

Comment: So post the screenshot I have asked for + Make sure you capture errors of the `ftp_put` to narrow down the problem. It seems that you have PHP reporting disabled.

Comment: because in your $source_file you doesn't have a file, just a file name, if you want to use file at uplaod directyl use the tmp_name like this :  $_FILES['files']['tmp_name']; 

But becarfull it's risky for cybersecurity this kind of usage; Because you upload file without any verification